# Custom sorting of file names

Tags: perl, sorting

I have a list of files:

```
TC-00001-(null)-20141027-204159FN.tif
TC-00020-(null)-20141027-203422FN.tif
```

etc

I need to process these files in an ordered way, but not the default way that `sort {$a cmp $b}`, gives me. Currently, it is sorting according to the `TC-0000X` numeration.

I would in fact like to sort according to the last number (`204159` and `203422`) before the `FN` characters. This is read as a sort of simplified time stamp `20:14:59 and 20:34:22`.

The sampling frequency of these files is one second, so this time-stamp uniquely identifies the file.

How can I sort in perl with this number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort allows you to define custom sorts that'll sort by any algorithm you like.

All the sub needs to is return positive, zero or negative - much like `cmp` or `<=>` do.

`$a` and `$b` are special variables used for this purpose.

So in your case:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub compare_last {
    #first we extract the values we're interested in...
    my ( $a_last ) = ( $a =~ m/(\d+)FN\./ );
    my ( $b_last ) = ( $b =~ m/(\d+)FN\./ );

 #   print "GOT: $a_last, $b_last, \n";

    #then we return the comparison. <=> is numeric, but you could use cmp. 
    #or manually set your own return codes - sort doesn't care, just bear in mind that 
    #each element is compared so you can end up with some pretty fruity results if you 
    #return a random number or something. 
    return ( $a_last <=> $b_last ); 
}

print sort compare_last <DATA> ;


## some dummy data

__DATA__
TC-00001-(null)-20141027-204159FN.tif
TC-00020-(null)-20141027-203422FN.tif
TC-00001-(null)-20141027-204159FN.tif
TC-00020-(null)-20141027-123456FN.tif
TC-00001-(null)-20141027-332FN.tif
TC-00020-(null)-20141027-018234FN.tif
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This is sort of confusing though, because how does Perl know that $a_last has anything to do with the $a variable?

Comment: It doesn't. It's looking at the return code of that subroutine, when given particular values of `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: `my ($a_last, $b_last) = map /(\d+)FN\./, $a,$b;`

Comment: Whilst you're right, and map's a neat solution - it still makes my head hurt, so I'm reluctant to suggest it's use to someone :)

Comment: map is only useful to reduce code/regex redundancy, but it might impose some performance impact considering this is not Schwartzian, and function gets called quite a few times.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a one-liner using [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) (which, like the other `List::*` modules, has an [XS version](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy::XS) for efficiency).

```
perl -MList::UtilsBy::XS=nsort_by -wle 'print nsort_by { /(\d+)FN[.]/ ? $1 : -1 } <>' filelist.txt
```